# Images being rendered as SVGs in Frontity React

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, foogallery, frontity

I have an issue with Frontity React, where it loads up featured images fine and some other images, but quite a lot of image which are added to the page either from a plugin (such as foogallery)

```
<figure class="fg-item-inner"><a href="7yKPcJk.jpg" target="_self" data-attachment-id="206" class="fg-thumb"><span class="fg-image-wrap"><span height="300" width="200" class="css-pxqjd2-Container e16qyzlb0"><img alt="" class="frontity-lazy-image skip-lazy fg-image" loading="lazy" width="200" height="300" data-src-fg="2109218829.jpg" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22300%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20300%22%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"></span></span><span class="fg-image-overlay"></span></a><figcaption class="fg-caption"><div class="fg-caption-inner"></div></figcaption></figure>
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

FooGallery adds a placeholder SVG for its lazy loading, which is replaced when the gallery JavaScript runs. You can disable lazy loading for the gallery (or for all galleries via settings page) which will stop this behavior.

Comment: this is great and fixed the image problem, thankyou so much :)

Comment: only problem i have now is css seems to be not working on images (width 100%) and also javascript on a slider

Comment: Please can you log a ticket and our support team will pick it up and assist : https://fooplugins.com/support/